# Can we get location from android service if app is closed and removed from recent apps

Tags: android, service, android-service, locationlistener

Hi all I saw few samples of getting location in background using android service. It worked fine when app is closed but app is not removed from recent apps. Once app is removed from recent apps it stops getting location. I just wanted to make sure if it is like that or not.

Am using a service with location listener to get location. I used this sample from So [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535703/best-way-to-get-user-gps-location-in-background-in-android). but it doesnt return location when removed from recent apps.

Comment: did you added the service in your manifest file?

Comment: yes i did add in manifest

Answer (score 0):

If you use `service`, you can override `onStartCommand` and return `START_STICKY`. Read more about it on this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY)