# Unable to get GPS location without internet on xiaomi devices

Tags: gps, location, locationmanager

I am using the following code to get location in a background service according to this answer

[Best way to get user GPS location in background in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535703/best-way-to-get-user-gps-location-in-background-in-android)

This issue is only found on xiaomi devices but it works as expected on other devices.

Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

String provider = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(

provider, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,

mLocationListeners[0]);