# Get continuous location using service even after app killed from recent drawer

Tags: android, android-service, google-geolocation, google-location-services

I started Service from main activity like;-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyLocationService.class);
startService(intent);
```

MyLocationService class looks like:-

```
public class MyLocationService extends Service implements
        LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private static final String TAG = MyLocationService.class.getSimpleName();
    public static Location mCurrentLocation;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: ");
        initiateGooglePlayService();
    }
    public void initiateGooglePlayService() {
        Log.e(TAG, "initiateGooglePlayService: ");
        if (isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10.0f);
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand: ");
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onBind: ");
        return null;
    }
    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        Log.e(TAG, "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable: ");
        int status = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
        return ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status;
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onConnected: ");
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended: ");
    }
    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        Log.e(TAG, "startLocationUpdates: ");
        try {
            PendingResult<Status> pendingResult;
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                return;
            }
            pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        } catch (IllegalStateException ignored) {
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location.getLongitude());
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mCurrentLocation = location;
            Intent intent = new Intent("GPSLocationUpdates");
            intent.putExtra("location", location);
         LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
            Toast.makeText(this, "location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionFailed: ");
    }
}
```

**I never stop the service anywhere.**

But still I am unable to get the control of **onLocationChange()**.

My motive is that, **I need continuous location to do some background operation**. It worked in lollipop sometimes. But it is not working in Marshmallow and nougat and even kitkat also. I searched but could not get the proper idea. Please let me know, where i am going wrong. Any suggestion accepted.

I am using following dependency for location;-

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'
```

Comment: I cant speak for everyone, but if I close an app from recent I want it to close and stop running **all** of its code

Comment: are you facing this issue on some devices or all Marshmallow devices

Comment: @ĜüptåŠhãsĥwæt it worked in lollipop sometimes, but not worked in any other device. I tested it in Nougat, Kitkat, Marshmallow.

Comment: have you given the Marshmallow permissions to your app??

Comment: @ShaifaliPundir YES, Even I given location permission from device setting also for test. But its fine.

Comment: @NickA  you are right, but i am developing business app, so there is a requirement to do some operation in background.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535703/best-way-to-get-user-gps-location-in-background-in-android

Comment: @KailasBhakade ahh, well internal apps are a different matter :)

Comment: Did u moved your device from one place to another as you have given    distance 10 ft.your device has to move more than 10ft as u mentioned in your code

Comment: @SachinGawai Yes. I did this as well. Should I change it 10ft to something else.

Comment: @NickA yes, any suggestion???

Comment: @SachinGawai its not ft. its meter.

Comment: Yes make it 100 meters and see what happens

Comment: @KailasBhakade try removing ` mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10.0f);` line.

Comment: Yes make it 100 meters and see what happens

Comment: @chandil03  ok, let me check.

Comment: @chandil03 its working fine for all devices after removed this line 
 - > mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10.0f);` Thank You very much, But Not working in Nougat.

Comment: @KailasBhakade your code will work with that line also, but you need to move your device location by 10 meters. Try writing test cases using location mocking.

Comment: @chandil03 okzz. But is anything is wrong in code or should i do something else? Because not working for nougat.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [HyperTrack](https://www.hypertrack.com/) SDK to get the location updates in the background. Get more insight about the reliability of SDK [here](https://docs.hypertrack.com/sdks/reliability.html) in different conditions.

First [Setup](https://www.hypertrack.com/) the SDK

After setting up the SDK you just need to set the Callback to receive the location updates.

```
HyperTrack.setCallback(new HyperTrackEventCallback() {
@Override
public void onEvent ( @NonNull final HyperTrackEvent event){
    switch (event.getEventType()) {
        case HyperTrackEvent.EventType.LOCATION_CHANGED_EVENT:
            Log.d(TAG, "onEvent: Location Changed");
            HyperTrackLocation hyperTrackLocation = event.getLocation();
            LatLng latLng = hyperTrackLocation.getLatLng();
            updateCurrentLocationMarker(event.getLocation());
            break;
    }
}
}
```

(Disclaimer: I work at HyperTrack.)

Comment: As Oreo has put a limitation on background service so SDK needs to keep a sticky notification to run a service as foreground.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**Check out my Github post i did the same for Taxi clone**/

Link ---> https://github.com/yash786agg/GPS/

Note: Remember to remove or comment the below mentioned code if you want the latitude 
and latitude even when the application is in background.

    if(networkUtilObj != null)
    {
        networkUtilObj.disconnectGoogleApiClient();
    }
```

Comment: Is it work even app killed from recent also. Because I am looking for this. If application is in background then my code worked.

Comment: yes i will work but do remember don't 
 call "networkUtilObj.disconnectGoogleApiClient();" anywhere that sample code contains the same line

Comment: @KailasBhakade if an app is killed from recent app drawer there is no way to do whatever you are looking for. Until you have a use case that can awake your app by launching it from Broadcast receiver.

Comment: @chandil03 OK, Thank You.