# How to use GPS Service in android

Tags: android, gps, location, google-location-services

I'm working on Android project that related to GPS I still new to android so I don't know a lot about it.

My project is an app where it calculates the distance between user location and a specified other location so if the distance is less than (X) say 1KM the app will send a notification to the user.[[I know how to calculate the distance between two
locations]].

My problem is: how can I do this even if the user didn't open the app (I mean if there's anyway that I can make the app calculates the distance in the background while the app is closed).so I want the GPS feature works in the background.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you can use [service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) for that

Comment: oh thanks I will check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a service for background process.

For your question for getting location, you should try these links:

[Best way to get user GPS location in background in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535703/best-way-to-get-user-gps-location-in-background-in-android)

[Get GPS location via a service in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828639/get-gps-location-via-a-service-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this problem was simply :-

you can use **Services** for working in the background (when the Activity isn't showing)

check this : -[Get GPS location via a service in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828639/get-gps-location-via-a-service-in-android)

**if you want this service to run for ever, even if the app is closed/killed you can use broadcast receivers **

Answer (score -1):

User `services`. They are simple to use and all you need.

Here is [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

A **service** is another component of an android application (like activity). You need to define the service in manifest. After that you could start the device using `startService` (intent). If you need to take some info (communicate with one activity) you can use `bindService` instead of `startService`. (Also need to implement `onBind`).

Another solution is to sendData using a broadcast receiver. Or you can simple set a notification in service and use it.

Comment: I'm new to android.... so I don't know a lot about it.....what do you mean by services ??

Comment: @JamalAl-kelani the same thing I gave you link to

Answer (score -1):

To get the app to run in the background, you'll need to learn about a service.
Service is a service that causes applications to run in the background such as gps, notification and more ..

link:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html