# Custom extension element in Stanza for Smack 4.1.4

Tags: smack, asmack

I am moving my android application from asmack-android library to Smack 4.1.4. I have some PacketExtensions in the asmack version of Smack, which uses PacketExtension and PacketExtensionProvider classes to handle. Since the PacketExtension is deprecated in Smack 4.1.4, I am confused among the classes and interfaces ExtensionElement, DataPacketExtension, ExtensionElementProvider , DefaultExtensionElement. Could any one of you give me an example of creating an extension which can be added with stanza and parse back...https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware /smack/packet/DefaultExtensionElement.htmlhttps://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware /smack/provider/ExtensionElementProvider.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured it out.... Here is the solution for it...

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.DefaultExtensionElement;

public class IM_FileSharing_Extension extends DefaultExtensionElement implements
    IM_Commons_Extension_FileSharing {

private String fileUrl;
private String fileType;
private String base64preview;
private String fileId;
private String fileSize;

public IM_FileSharing_Extension(String fileUrl, String fileType,
        String base64preview, String fileId, String fileSize) {
    super(FILE_TAG, XMLNS);
    this.fileUrl = fileUrl;
    this.fileType = fileType;
    this.base64preview = base64preview;
    this.fileId = fileId;
    this.fileSize = fileSize;
}

@Override
public String toXML() {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<" + FILE_TAG + " xmlns=\""
            + XMLNS + "\" ");
    sb.append(FILE_URL + "=\"" + fileUrl + "\" ");
    sb.append(FILE_ID + "=\"" + fileId + "\" ");
    sb.append(FILE_TYPE + "=\"" + fileType + "\" ");
    sb.append(FILE_SIZE + "=\"" + fileSize + "\">");
    sb.append("<" + FILE_PREVIEW_TAG + ">" + base64preview + "</"
            + FILE_PREVIEW_TAG + ">");
    sb.append("</" + FILE_TAG + ">");

    return sb.toString();
}

public String getFileUrl() {
    return fileUrl;
}

public void setFileUrl(String fileUrl) {
    this.fileUrl = fileUrl;
}

public String getBase64preview() {
    return base64preview;
}

public void setBase64preview(String base64preview) {
    this.base64preview = base64preview;
}

public String getFileId() {
    return fileId;
}

public void setFileId(String fileId) {
    this.fileId = fileId;
}

public String getFileType() {
    return fileType;
}

public void setFileType(String fileType) {
    this.fileType = fileType;
}

public String getFileSize() {
    return fileSize;
}

public void setFileSize(String fileSize) {
    this.fileSize = fileSize;
}

}
```

Provider for the above extension is as follows...

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.provider.ExtensionElementProvider;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.util.Log;

public class IM_FileSharingExtension_Provider extends
    ExtensionElementProvider<IM_FileSharing_Extension> implements
    IM_Commons_Extension_FileSharing {
static final String TAG = "file_extension";

@Override
public IM_FileSharing_Extension parse(XmlPullParser parser, int initialDepth)
        throws XmlPullParserException, IOException, SmackException {

    IM_FileSharing_Extension fileExtension = null;

    boolean stop = false;

    String n = null;

    int evtType;

    String fileUrl = null;
    String fileType = null;
    String fileId = null;
    String fileSize = null;
    while (!stop) {

        evtType = parser.getEventType();
        n = parser.getName();
        Log.d(TAG, "n:" + n + " evt:" + evtType);
        switch (evtType) {

        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:

            if (FILE_TAG.equals(n)) {

                fileUrl = parser.getAttributeValue("", FILE_URL);

                fileType = parser.getAttributeValue("", FILE_TYPE);

                fileId = parser.getAttributeValue("", FILE_ID);

                fileSize = parser.getAttributeValue("", FILE_SIZE);

                evtType = parser.next();

            }

            if (FILE_PREVIEW_TAG.equals(parser.getName())) {
                String basePreview = parser.nextText();
                fileExtension = new IM_FileSharing_Extension(fileUrl,
                        fileType, basePreview, fileId, fileSize);
            }

            evtType = parser.next();

            break;

        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

            if (parser.getName().equals(FILE_TAG)) {
                return fileExtension;
            }
            evtType = parser.next();

        }

    }
    return null;
}

}
```

And should be added in Provider manager as following....

```
ProviderManager.addExtensionProvider(
            IM_Commons_Extension_FileSharing.FILE_TAG,
            IM_Commons_Extension_FileSharing.XMLNS,
            new IM_FileSharingExtension_Provider());
```

Answer (score 24):

```
Message message = new Message();
message.setStanzaId("923442621149");
message.setType(Type.chat);
message.setBody("shanraisshan");
Log.e("message --->", message.toXML().toString());
```

This will produce the following stanza

```
<message id='923442621149' type='chat'><body>shanraisshan</body></message>
```

---

### 1. ***CUSTOM EXTENSION STANZA TYPE-1***

In order to generate below *custom extension stanza*

```
<message id='923442621149' type='chat'><body>shanraisshan</body>
<reply xmlns='shayan:reply' rText='this is custom attribute'/>
</message>
```

where **reply** is a custom extension, which contains

1. **Element** (reply)
2. **Namespace** (shayan:reply)

the list of default xmpp namespaces are available at [Official XMPP website](http://xmpp.org/registrar/namespaces.html)

Do following steps

***1. Add ReplyExtension.java in your project***

***ReplyExtension.java***

```
package com.xmpp.extensions;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.DefaultExtensionElement;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.ExtensionElement;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.provider.EmbeddedExtensionProvider;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.XmlStringBuilder;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Shayan Rais (http://shanraisshan.com)
 * created on 9/7/2016
 */
public class ReplyExtension implements ExtensionElement  {

    public static final String NAMESPACE = "shayan:reply";
    public static final String ELEMENT = "reply";

    String rText = null;

    static final String ATTRIBUTE_REPLY_TEXT = "rText";

    @Override
    public String getElementName() {
        return ELEMENT;
    }

    @Override
    public String getNamespace() {
        return NAMESPACE;
    }

    @Override
    public XmlStringBuilder toXML() {
        XmlStringBuilder xml = new XmlStringBuilder(this);
        xml.attribute(ATTRIBUTE_REPLY_TEXT, getReplyText());
        xml.closeEmptyElement();
        return xml;
    }

//__________________________________________________________________________________________________
    public void setReplyText(String _rText) {
        rText = _rText;
    }

    public String getReplyText() {
        return rText;
    }

//__________________________________________________________________________________________________
    public static class Provider extends   EmbeddedExtensionProvider<ReplyExtension> {
        @Override
        protected ReplyExtension createReturnExtension(String    currentElement, String currentNamespace, Map<String, String> attributeMap,    List<? extends ExtensionElement> content) {
            ReplyExtension repExt = new ReplyExtension();
            repExt.setReplyText(attributeMap.get(ATTRIBUTE_REPLY_TEXT));
            return repExt;
        }
    }
}
```

***2. Register ReplyExtension in your Provider Manager***

```
ProviderManager.addExtensionProvider(ReplyExtension.ELEMENT, ReplyExtension.NAMESPACE, new ReplyExtension.Provider());
```

---

**FOR SENDING MESSAGES**

You can generate the ***custom extension stanza TYPE-1*** by using following code

```
Message message = new Message();
message.setStanzaId("923442621149");
message.setType(Type.chat);
message.setBody("shanraisshan");
//adding custom reply extension
ReplyExtension repExt = new ReplyExtension();
repExt.setReplyText("this is custom attribute");
message.addExtension(repExt);
Log.e("message --->", message.toXML().toString());
```

**DURING RECEIVING MESSAGES**

Now during receiving ***custom extension stanzas***, you need to cast the extension to get attribute values.

```
//check for message with reply extension
ExtensionElement packetExtension =  message.getExtension(ReplyExtension.NAMESPACE);
ReplyExtension repExt = (ReplyExtension)packetExtension;
if(repExt!=null) {
    Log.e("--->", " ---  LOG REPLY EXTENSION ---");
    Log.e("--->", repExt.toXML() + "");
    Log.e("--->", repExt.getReplyText() + ""); //this is custom attribute
}
```

---

**_______________________________________________________**

### 2. ***CUSTOM EXTENSION STANZA TYPE-2***

In order to generate below *custom extension stanza*

```
<message id='923442621149' type='chat'><body>shanraisshan</body>
<reply xmlns='shayan:reply'><rText>this is custom attribute</rText></reply>
</message>
```

**FOR SENDING MESSAGES**

You can generate the ***custom extension stanza TYPE-2*** by using following code

```
Message message = new Message();
message.setStanzaId("923442621149");
message.setType(Type.chat);
message.setBody("shanraisshan");
//adding custom reply extension
DefaultExtensionElement repExt = new DefaultExtensionElement("reply", "shayan:reply");
repExt.setValue("rText", "this is custom attribute");
message.addExtension(repExt);
Log.e("message --->", message.toXML().toString());
```

**DURING RECEIVING MESSAGES**

```
DefaultExtensionElement repExt = (DefaultExtensionElement) message.getExtension("shayan:reply");
if(repExt!=null) {
    Log.e("--->", " ---  LOG REPLY EXTENSION ---");
    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), repExt.getValue("rText"));
}
```